# Need to select ALL columns while using COUNT/Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, group-by

Ok so I have a table in which ONE of the columns have a FEW REPEATING records.

My task is to select the REPEATING records with all attributes.

CustID FN LN DOB City State

the DOB has some repeating values which I need to select from the whole table and list all columns of all records that are same within the DOB field..

My try...

```
Select  DOB, COUNT(DOB) As 'SameDOB' from Table1

group by DOB

HAVING (COUNT(DOB) > 1)
```

This only returns two columns and one row 1st column is the DOB column that occurs more than once and the 2nd column gives count on how many.

I need to figure out a way to list all attributes not just these two...

Please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: you just list them all in the `SELECT` and don't forget to include into the `GROUP BY`. am I missing something? did you try it and it doesn't give you the result you expect?

Comment: @PavelVeller - normally, yes, group by works but when you're trying to find dupes, the group by against all fields will only find counts on the distinct rows so the count has to be placed inside a subquery or CTE.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think a more general solution is to use windows functions:

```
select *
from (select *, count(*) over (partition by dob) as NumDOB
      from table
     ) t
where numDOB > 1
```

The reason this is more general is because it is easy to change to duplicates across two or more columns.

Comment: need to read up on one more thing...partition. Thanks...learning alot tonight.

Answer (score 9):

```
Select * 
FROM  Table1 T
WHERE T.DOB IN( Select   I.DOB
                FROM     Table1 I
                GROUP BY I.DOB
                HAVING   COUNT(I.DOB) > 1)
```

Comment: Using the 'IN' clause against a subquery can be quite slow, just an FYI.

Comment: @ChrisGessler. Fixed the from thing, but I'm not sure `IN` is slower.

Comment: LOL - select dob from dob group by dob having dob order by dob....  But yes, it's well known that the IN clause is slower than joins.  http://www.bennadel.com/blog/940-SQL-Optimization-Case-Study-JOIN-Clause-vs-IN-Clause.htm

Comment: @ChrisGessler. Better than `SELECT DOG FROM DOG GROUP BY DOG...`

Comment: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference Is the error I got when I ran your suggested query

Comment: @JohnSmith. I didn't get your comment.

Comment: @ChrisGessler. I read that post, I don't know the guy doesn't seem to an expert at all. Read the comments to his blog, readers teach him `EXIST` . What the???

Comment: @gdoron That is the error I got when I ran the query you suggested. Not sure what it means though

Comment: @JohnSmith. Try it again with alias for the inner table.

Comment: Oh sweett..thanX...besides the blog link posted, is there any other good sites that gives good intro/intermediate/advance (all if possible) info about joins, subquery, partition, etc?

Comment: ahaha...thanX for the wiki leak.

Answer (score 4):

Try joining with a subquery, which will also allow you to see the count

```
select t.*, a.SameDOB from Table1 t
join (
  Select  DOB, COUNT(DOB) As 'SameDOB' from Table1 
  group by DOB 
  HAVING (COUNT(DOB) > 1) 
) a on a.dob = t.dob
```

Comment: Ahh...that works. I am still a newb when it comes to subquery. I guess I need to focus on that really hard in upcoming days. I need to find a book that covers this in good detail.

Comment: @JohnSmith - MSDN is a good read when you have some spare time.

Comment: Now the other part is, find the youngest cust and list all cust with that DOB. In other words, I will have AT LEAST one record in the entity with all attributes....

Comment: Select top(1) DateOfBirth, COUNT(DateOfBirth) As 'YoungestCustomer' From Customers
Group by DateOfBirth
Order by DateOfBirth desc

Comment: Now, that gives me two columns. One with the DOB of the youngest cust and the other with the count of the youngest cust. I need to then list that youngest customer info (other attributes)...Since I have only one customer with that dob, I will have one row. But having trouble figuring this out...gonna try this subquery format and see what I can get.

Comment: Sweet, This works,Select * FROM  Tab t
WHERE t.dob IN ( Select Top(1) i.dob FROM tab d
GROUP BY i.dob
Order by i.dob desc)

Answer (score -1):

```
select * 
from table1, (select count(*) from table1) as cnt
```

Comment: Please give your Code with proper explanation. Code only answers are not appreciated.